# jQuery Not Functioning on Text Input Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why the `click` event is not firing ?

```js
$( ".content" ).on("click", function() {
  alert( "This is Clicked" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" class="content" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `class` twice. Try this:

```
<input type="text" class="content form-control" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `<input type="text" class="form-control content" />` for `<input type="text" class="form-control" class="content" >`

```js
$(".content").on("click", function() {
  alert("This is Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="form-control content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').click(function(){
       alert('I have done');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control content" />
```